# Ion-tabs com classe tabs-top no iOS?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou criando um aplicativo que usa tabs para navegação e defini as tabs para o topo com `tabs-top`. No Android funciona certinho mas no iOS as tabs ficam atrás do `header`, como resolver isso ?

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-top tabs-color-active-positive">

      <!-- Empresas Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Empresas" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/emp">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-emp"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Servicos Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Serviços" icon-off="ion-ios-people-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-people" href="#/tab/serv">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-serv"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Acessar Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Acessar" icon-off="ion-ios-world-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-world" href="#/tab/acesso" ng-click="isLogged();">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-acesso"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>


      <!-- Anunciantes Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Anunciar" icon-off="ion-ios-star-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-star" href="#/tab/anuncio">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-anuncio"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <!-- Info Tab -->
      <ion-tab title="Informações" icon-off="ion-ios-information-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/info">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-info"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar em app.js no .config assim:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.platform.ios.tabs.position('top');
```

Neste link tem mais info sobre: [$ionicConfigProvider](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/)

Answer (score 0):

Como é só no iphone você pode setar no css para dar um top maior.

```
.platform-ios .tabs-top{
    top: 90px !important;
 }
```

Eu coloquei 90px, mas se não ficar bom você pode aumentar. No iphone geralmente as tabs ficam na parte de baixo.

Answer (score -1):

Use isto no q vc qr que fique na frente:

```
z-index : 9999;
```